# Prevent duplicate code for different web pages with same menu

Tags: php, layout, anchor

I have a menu that wants to change only the content.

I wanted a separate files for different pages to organize.

I could save menu in a separate php file and include that in the main page.

Still seems a bit repetitive when there are more than 10 menus.

I know there is an anchor tag navigation that updates content part with jQuery.

But I kinda don't like that # tag in the address bar for some reason (or shouldn't I?)

Is there a better way to manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think that to add just one line with include into each file is indeed such a repetitive task. 99% of local folks a way more repetitive in thir code.
2. However, if you want something more intelligent, you can create one program file contains menu, and many data files, shown according to user choice

here is a very simple example

```
<a href="index.php">Main page</a><br>
<a href=?about>About</a><br>
<a href=?links>Links</a><br>
<br><br> 
<? 
if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) { 
  $name="index"; 
} else { 
  $name=basename($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); 
} 
$file="txt/".$name.".htm"; 
if (is_readable($file)) { 
  readfile($file);
} else { 
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
  exit;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this ^_^much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

> I could save menu in a separate php file and include that in the main page.

Yes. Do that.

> I know there is an anchor tag navigation that updates content part with jQuery.

Breaks search engines. Depends on JS. [Avoid it](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll look into one of the other website I created with anchor tag nav. 
Much appreciated :)